# If you place enough sand, does it start making desert mobs spawn in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I have seen some desert mobs near my tower after I used my new sand gun and sand was stacked up everywhere and I was wondering if the sand was spawning desert mobs just like how if you put crimson seeds in your area crimson mobs start spawning and it turns crimson sort of the same thing but different.

Please tell me if you know the answer.

Comment: In general, biomes are defined by the blocks present, not by specific areas of a world.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, when you place enough sand in an area, then it turns into an artificial desert biome. But you need at least 1500(desktop, console, mobile) or 1000(other) blocks of sand. You can tell that you successfully created an artificial biome if you have a spot where the background and music change when you move your character there.

More information on this on [the wiki](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Guide:Artificial_biomes).